# Inline option for enumitem

Tags: lists, document-classes, enumitem

I'm writing an article whith a specific document class. I want to create an inline list. Usually I use `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}` and

```
\begin{enumerate*}
\item
\end{enumerate*}
```

for this purpose.

The class already has the `enumitem` package loaded, but without the `inline` option. Is there an option or command for add the `inline` option in the main text, avoiding changes in the document class?

**Note:** I'm using `mdpi` class provided by Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute

Comment: There's a command called (something like) PassOptionsToPackage, which you can put before your documentclass command, perhaps that might help?

Comment: @cmhughes It helps!, what is the correct instruction? \PassOptionsToPackage?

Comment: @DanielValencia: `\PassOptionsToPackage{inline}{enumitem}` before `\documentclass`.

Comment: You also can write `inline` among the document class options.

Comment: You can also say `\begin{enumerate}[inline]` even if the `inline` option isn't given to the package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- you could use `\PassOptionsToPackage` as in the following:

  `\PassOptionsToPackage{inline}{enumitem}
  \documentclass{mdpi}`
- otherwise you could pass the `inline` option to the `documentclass`
  `\documentclass[inline]{mdpi}`

Here's a complete MWE; note that I've used the `draft` option so that the logo from the document class wasn't used.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{inline}{enumitem}
\documentclass[draft]{mdpi}

\Title{title}
\Author{cmh}
\address{}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate*}
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

For reference, I downloaded `mdpi.cls` from here: http://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex. I created `/texmf/tex/latex/mdpi` and unzipped the folder to that directory. See [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te) for more information.